# Excel buttons to call WPF windows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, excel, add-in

I have a CSharp (.NET) application that has created an add-in with a ribbon in Excel. I have buttons in the ribbon. I want to be able to click on the buttons, and open WPF windows.

The code looks like

```
 private void OnNewButtonAction(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
 {                    
      var window = new View.MyWindow()
      {
         DataContext = new ViewModel.MyViewModel(),
      };
      window.Show();
  }
```

Where MyWindow is a class of type System.Windows.Window. MyWindow has its own xaml file, which has radio buttons, text fields etc. When I try to run this - and click on the button, I get an XML parse exception as - "'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception".

Is it possible to invoke wpf windows from excel add-ins? What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have already looked at
[Using WPF Controls in Office Solutions](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e77413dc-2c33-4723-9425-49c705c49df6/c-excel-ribbon-button-to-open-wpf-as-dialog-box?forum=exceldev) and it doesn't work. And it adds a separate pane to excel, which is not what I am looking at.

Comment: here is a link that has some step-by-step instructions to do exactly what you are trying to do.. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e77413dc-2c33-4723-9425-49c705c49df6/c-excel-ribbon-button-to-open-wpf-as-dialog-box?forum=exceldev

Comment: I have seen this link. I think it is about adding a pane to Excel, on top of which the wpf application is pasted. I want a separate dialog box, not connected to the Excel app.

Answer (score 5):

You should use Excel-DNA. Its a really useful piece of software designed just for things like this, it helps to implement Excel with WPF, and you shouldn't have any problems again.

you can get it [Here](http://exceldna.codeplex.com/)

If however you don't want that there is a step by step tutorial here on how to do it.

You may try to define a WPF window as a custom control and add it to the custom pane of the word. Have a look at the following link, pleases:

[Using WPF Controls in Office Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb772076.aspx)

You may have a look at this link as well:

[Office 2007 Excel Addin - WPF ComboBox Collapses when Expanded](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/919d2c2c-58a7-4d35-9526-0e5582a483f2/)

The common way we add WPF control to custompane is:

1. Create an Excel add-in project
2. Add user control (WPF) name UserControl1 and add reference to System.xaml
3. Code the WPF control and Build the project successfully
4. Add User Control from Window Form collection, named the control as UserControl2
5. Drag and drop a UserControl1 to UserControl2, assign the position as you like
6. Code the ThisAddIn.cs in this way:

   ```
    UserControl1 myWPF;

    UserControl2 winformControl;

    Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane pane;

    System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost myHost;







    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    myWPF = new UserControl1();

    winformControl = new UserControl2();

    pane = CustomTaskPanes.Add(winformControl, "WPFControl");

    pane.Visible = true;

    pane.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionRight; 
    }
   ```

We can use the button to control the pane's visible property.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Where do you get CustomTaskPanes from please? So there is no way for me to create a separate dialog that is not attached to Excel?

Comment: You can create a basic custom task pane in two steps:

    1.Create a user interface for your custom task pane by adding Windows Forms controls to a UserControl object.

  2.  Instantiate the custom task pane by passing the user control to the CustomTaskPaneCollection object in your add-in. This collection returns a new CustomTaskPane object that you can use to modify the appearance of the task pane and respond to user events.

Comment: If this has answered will you please mark your question as answered by me